# redirect Location but not URL

Tags: redirect, express

How do I redirect the user to a different route without redirecting the URL in vanilla Express? For example, if I have the routes

```
express = require('express');
app = express();

app.route('/old').get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/new');
});

app.route('/new').get(function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is the new route');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and I point my browser to `http://localhost:3000/old`, the application successfully redirects, and the page says `This is the new route`, but the URL has changed, as well, to `http://localhost:3000/new`. How do I get the application to redirect to the `new` route but keep the old URL (`http://localhost:3000/old`)?

I'm fine installing another middleware (as if I don't already have a million already), but ideally, I'd like to do this without extra middleware. Also, I'm doing this completely in Express.js, without PHP, nginx, or anything else. I will be using Angular.js in my application, but this seems like more of a server-side behavior, rather than client-side. I do redirect on the client side sometimes, but I don't want to do it all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

rather than redirect, how about just send a get request using [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

and do a callback to update content.

```
var request = require('request');

app.route('/old').get(function(req, res, next) {

  request.get('/new', function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err) {
      req.send(body);
    }
  });         
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of new to Node/Express, if you couldn't already tell. Now, what's the difference between this and making a request without that module? Or does the module just make it easier?

Comment: well, it made things a lot easier, kind of like XMLHttpRequest object vs $.ajax I think.

Comment: Interesting. OK, well, looks like I'm using the `request` module as well. Thanks.

Comment: this works but care must be taken with MIME types.  when the request is a .css it sends the wrong type

Comment: This lets your server handle the page load, which is not great if you use CDN etc

Comment: What if we are hosting the file on some other externals server, and want it to handle the load and don't want to handle the load for transferring file ourselves ?

Comment: `req.send` is not a function - I guess you meant `res.send`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a helper method that both routes use:

```
express = require('express');
app = express();

const newHandler = function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is the new route');
};
app.route('/old').get(newHandler);
app.route('/new').get(newHandler);

app.listen(3000);
```

Note, `req.url` will be different inside `newHandler` for the two different routes, so you may need to handle that.